# Plot poseStamped topic in rqt_plot/RViz

Tags: ros, rviz, rqt-plot, posestamped

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a topic which is built like that:

```
int32 id
float64 size
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped pose
```

I am seeing it if I do rostopic list and rostopic echo without any problem. I would like to see it through rqt_plot and/or RViz but I am not able to do so.

The topic is named

```
/apriltag2_detections
```

I do

```
rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot
```

And I can arrive only to see the field id and size. Like from the following screenshot (you can also see a rostopic echo output on the right of the image):

[image: image description]

Could you tell me why? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249736/plot-posestamped-topic-in-rqt_plot/rviz/) by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi fabbro,

Because `detections` is an array, you will have to add `/apriltag2_tag_detections/detections[0]/pose/pose/position` and `/apriltag2_tag_detections/detections[0]/pose/pose/orientation` to `rqt_plot` to plot the values of the *first* detection.

As for showing this pose in Rviz, I don't think Rviz is able to do that by default, but if you (also) publish just the pose on a separate topic, you can add a `Pose` display to Rviz that subscribes to that topic.

You can use `topic_tools` ([wiki link](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools)) to automatically transform your messages to a `geometry_msgs/Pose` by running:

```
rosrun topic_tools transform /apriltag2_tag_detections /apriltag2_tag_detections_pose geometry_msgs/Pose 'm.detections[0].pose.pose'
```

This will create a new topic that transforms your messages into poses that Rviz can easily visualize.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2016-12-11**:
Hey, I tried to do that. But as you can see from my figure I can only add `/apriltag2_tag_detections/detections`
I have no idea why.

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2016-12-12**:
Whoops just noticed a typo, should ofourse be `apriltag2_tag_detections/detections/pose/pose/position`. Did you try explicitly typing that whole string? or even `apriltag2_tag_detections/detections/pose/pose/position/x`? I have found that the suggestions that rqt makes aren't always complete..

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2016-12-12**:
I tried, yes, but it does not work. It is really strange for me.

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2016-12-12**:
I don't see where `detections` comes from in your msg definition, does that happen to an array? In that case you will need `apriltag2_tag_detections/detections[0]/pose/pose/position`

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2016-12-12**:
Yes, finally. This was the problem. I put `apriltag2_tag_detections/detections[0]/pose/pose/position`  and it is working. If you edit your answer I can also accept it to *reward* the help you gave me :) . Thanks again.

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2016-12-12**:
edited, you're welcome!

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2016-12-12**:
Thanks, I also upvoted all your comments.